# Force Xcode to create a Finder folder when creating a new project group

Tags: xcode, directory-structure

For a while now I have been creating folders in Finder, then adding them as groups to my Xcode projects. Is there a way to force Xcode to do the reverse and save me a step -- i.e., create a new folder when I add a group to the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, the only thing you can do is to click on "Add folder..." button on "Add files" window.

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but from Xcode 9 onwards, it works exactly like you wanted. Hope you didn't quit iOS since then.

Comment: It only took six years! :)